# VS Code not creating new line on pressing Enter, but works with Ctrl+Enter

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm facing an issue with VS Code where pressing the "Enter" key in JavaScript files does not create a new line, but pressing "Ctrl+Enter" does. The issue does not occur in Python files because of a source called Python indent. Check the image below

[image]

I've tried the following solutions but they did not work:

Toggling word wrap using "Ctrl+Shift+P" and "View: Toggle Word Wrap" command.
Checking and resetting keyboard shortcuts for the "Insert Line Below" command.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds highly unusual. Try checking for any misbehaving extensions using [bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) or disable them all to rule out an extension issue

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting the bisect method! It helped me identify that one of my extensions was causing the issue. I really appreciate your help! vscode-styled-components was the extension that was doing the problem, link- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=diegolincoln.vscode-styled-components

Comment: Nice find. Might be worth checking their [issues list](https://github.com/dilincoln/vscode-styled-components/issues) and raising a bug

Comment: yeah sure, I will raise the bug